# Cell mode in Python editors

Tags: python, matlab, ide

In recent versions of MATLAB, one can execute a code region between two lines starting with `%%` using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Such region is called a [code cell](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_env/brqxeeu-259.html), and it allows for fast code testing and debugging.

E.g.

```
%% This is the beginning of the 1st cell

a = 5;    

%% This is the end of the 1st cell and beginning of the 2nd cell

% This is just a comment
b = 6;

%% This is the end of the 2nd cell
```

Are there any python editors that support a similar feature?

**EDIT:** I just found that [Spyderlib](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/) supports "block" execution (code regions separated with blank lines) with F9, but as the [this thread](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/detail?id=117) mentions, this feature is still not very robust (in particular in combination with loops).

Comment: Interesting question (+1)... I'm curious though: what is this be useful for? Between the interactive shell and the unittest + doctest moudules, I can't think of a situation in which "cells" would offer additional functionality. I never used "cell mode" in other languages either, so mine is an honest question, not a convolute way to say "it's not useful"! :)

Comment: I haven't used `unittest` nor `doctest` (I'll take a look at them). `Cell mode` in MATLAB is useful because it allows you to evaluate code while editing it by just pressing `Ctrl + Enter` anytime. The location of the cursor determines what cell (lines of code) is sent to the interpreter, and the state of the variables is kept between cell evaluations. In other words, the use of cells allows you to grow and test your code very organically by grouping lines into 'functional' blocks.

Comment: Some of the links are dead in this post and the syntax highlighting can be improved, I typed up a suggested edit for your post, see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/superlazyname/57467509cbab07a8d0c39b573b16b001) (click Raw for markdown source). Also from the looks of it the issue you mentioned with Spyder has been closed, are you still having trouble with block execution in looops?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Interactive Editor for Python [IEP](http://www.iep-project.org/) has a *Matlab-style cell notation to mark code sections (by starting a line with '##')*, and the shortcut by default is also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
## Cell one
"""
A cell is everything between two commands starting with '##'
"""
a = 3
b = 4
print('The answer is ' + str(a+b))

## Cell two

print('Hello World')
```

Comment: +1 nice find.  This even appears in the features list on the front page.

Comment: @AndréCaron: I've used this IDE before, but never knew this feature existed until now

Comment: Thanks @Amro, this is the closest implementation I have seen of a MATLAB-like cell in a Python editor. [Spyderlib](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/) relies on blank lines for the definition of blocks which [apparently](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/detail?id=117) is not very robust.

Answer (score 5):

Spyder3 defines a cell as all code between lines starting with `#%%`.

Run a cell with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, or run a cell and advance with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

**Spyder3 & PyCharm:** #%% or # %%

**Spyder3:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>: to run current cell, *Shift+Enter*: to run current cell and advance.

**PyCharm:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>: to run and advance

```
# %%

print('You are in cell 1')

# %%

print('You are in cell 2')
# %% 

print('You are in cell 3')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G59iy.png)

Comment: For PyCharm this seems to only be supported in the paid version, but I hope I'm wrong!

Answer (score 1):

[Pyscripter](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/) supports block execution. But it's Win only. And it's limited to select code block - > run it(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>). No notion of cells.

Answer (score 1):

IDLE with [IdleX](http://idlex.sourceforge.net) has support for Matlab-like and Sage-like cells using SubCodes. Code in between '##' markers can be executed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>. It also allows for indented markers so that indented code can be executed.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a vim plugin in which cells are delimited by ## . It sends cells to an ipython interpreter running in tmux. You can define key mappings to execute the current cell, execute current cell and move to next or execute the current line :

https://github.com/julienr/vim-cellmode

I recently started working on a similar plugin for Intellij PyCharm. It can send the cell to either the internal python console (which has some issues with plots) or to an ipython interpreter running in tmux :

https://github.com/julienr/pycharm-cellmode

Answer (score 0):

There is [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) that offers something like this. It is meant to be a python alternative to Matlab, you should take a look.

In a sage notebook, you write python commands within blocks that are pretty similar to matlab's cell.