# Separate sections in Python

Tags: python

I was wondering whether there is a **best practice** to separate chunks of code in Python. In MATLAB, for example, two comment signs (`%%`) create a code section. At the moment, I am doing:

```
####
## Import libraries
####

import _mssql #Binary here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pymssql

####
## Connect to db + Query the data
####

q_file = open ("query.txt", "r")
query = q_file.read().replace('\n', '')

##Connect to the database
conn = _mssql.connect(server='', user='',
                      password='', database='')

##Query the database
conn.execute_query(query)
for row in conn:
    print(row)

####
## Data filtering
####

[...]
```

Comment: you can use the double quotes.. `"" ""`

Comment: In general I feel that when you need to divide your module into different chapters, that means that it's become too large and should have been split up over different files a while ago.

Comment: Or you're over-commenting.

Comment: The Sypder-IDE has Matlab like code cells (https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/editor.html#how-to-define-a-code-cell). To structure my code, I try to comment that way that when using sphinx (http://sphinx-doc.org/tutorial.html#autodoc) with numpydoc (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpydoc), I obtain a useful documentation. That results in a natural structuring through the comments.

Comment: as simple as: `#%%`

Comment: In my opinion, this is a valid question and it should not have been closed as opinion-based, but as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719972/cell-mode-in-python-editors). The answers below only address 'how to organize Python code in general', instead of recommending an alternative for Matlab's `%%` cell divider.

Answer (score 10):

**Top level** use modules, implement separate parts in their respective modules, then refer to those in your main:

```
import random
import time

if time.time() > random.random():
    pass
```

**Next level** (optional, use sparingly) use classes

```
class Foo:
    def function1():
        pass

class Bar:
    def function2():
        pass
```

**Next level**, what you need, use functions

```
def connect(...):
    filename = ...
    params = ...(filename)
    return mysql.connect(*params)

def mainloop(...):
    for xx in connect():
        pass
```

**Sublevel** use blocks

```
def foo(path=None, port=None):
    if not path:
        filename = ...
        path = ...(filename)

    if not port:
        foobar = ...
        port = ...(foobar)

    xxx.connect(path, port)
```

**Subsublevel** use blank lines and comments

```
def foo(...):
    bar.bar()

    assert path  # <-- this is essentially a comment
    smth_with(path)
    some_other()
    data = xxx.yyy()

    assert data
    foo = blahblah
    bar = lambda: blahblah
    filtered = filter(yada, data)

    # data is clean at this point  # <-- an actual comment
    for x, y in data:
        foo.bar.baz()
```

**Final thoughts** large comment blocks like in OQ show "code smell." You are right to start wondering how to organise your code at this point :)

Comment: You fail to show documentation strings at the file, module, class, and function level.  Those are essential to any code usability effort.

Comment: You are correct, yet omission was intended. OQ pertained to separating code into chunks, and I felt docstring could be misleading, as I am of opinion that there should only be one doc string per module, one per class, one per function; thus doc string cannot be used to separate two chunks of code.

Answer (score 8):

Python quite naturally offers a modular structure, and documentation strings for every level of structure.

Your comments generally would belong as function names or method descriptions.  Then the code reads naturally.  (Some comments are so obvious as to be useless, like "Import libraries".)

```
"""
Perform stuff.  Obviously this documentation should be more specific in reality.
"""

import _mssql  # Binary here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pymssql


def run_query(filename):
    """
    Open connection to database, run the query in the file, and
    return rows as a list.
    """
    rows = []

    # Minor tweak: "with" takes care of closing the file when you're done
    with open (filename, "r") as q_file:
        query = q_file.read().replace('\n', '')

    conn = _mssql.connect(server='', user='',
                      password='', database='')

    conn.execute_query(query)
    for row in conn:
        # Maybe use yield here instead of reading all the results into memory
        rows.append(row)

    return rows

def filter_rows(rows):
    """
    Filter a list of rows: Remove any rows containing 'Albuquerque'.
    """
    # ....

results = filter_rows(run_query("query.txt"))
```

See further [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) to guide your documentation efforts.